# AMP FX Works Locally, but not in Google's AMP Cache

Tags: amp-html

We have added `amp-fx="float-in-top"` for the header and `amp-fx="float-in-bottom"` for tags, which you can see below:

https://www.ccn.com/this-stat-will-make-facebook-amazons-antitrust-hearing-insanely-awkward/

It works fine locally and through the AMP validator, but if you search for the story and visit it in a Google cache, it does not work. The only thing that works on Google is the `amp-fx="fly-in-left"` for the post title.

We have also added video docking for YouTube videos. This works fine locally, but not on Google cached pages.

Comment: Looks like a bug. You should file an issue here: https://github.com/ampproject/amp.dev/issues